# if between int and int, display rows

Tags: php, if-statement

Well, I've been screwing around with this for about 6 hours and I just can't get it to work right. I'm sure it's just something stupid i'm doing, maybe your guys' fresh eyes can point it out.

```
$i = 0;
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT type, info, url FROM alerts WHERE username = '$user_logged_in' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 40");
$div_grid = '<div style="float:left;">';


while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    if ($i < 11){
    $display = '<a href="' . $row['info'] . '"><div class="' . $row['type'] . "_alert" . '" style="float:left; margin-left:-22px;"></div></a>';


    $div_grid .='<div style="float:left;">' . $display . '</div>';
    $i++;
    } 
    if ($i > 11){
        $display = '<a href="' . $row['info'] . '"><div class="' . $row['type'] . "_alert" . '" style="float:left; margin-left:-22px; margin-top:14px;"></div></a>';


    $div_grid .='<div style="float:left;">' . $display . '</div>';
    $i++;
    }

}
$div_grid .= '</div>';

echo $div_grid;
```

For some reason, I get the whole first line of these div outputs, but the second line isn't coming out. Except if I set the $i >= 11{ which then gives me TWO id 11s. Obviously i'm missing something crucial here. Any ideas?

Also, in the end, i'd like to make the if statements to be >= 10 && <= 20; which hasn't seemed to be working so far but I'm guessing there's an issue somewhere else first.

Comment: you have statements for less than 11 and more than 11 but never actually 11. So it will hit 11 and $i will remain the same and nothing will happen

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are incrementing `$i++` twice. It is also necessary to use `>=` since you will otherwise be missing row 11, and the loop will run with no output (`$1==11`, so it's not less than or greater than 11) until the end of your recordset.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    if ($i < 11){
        // first row
    } else {
        // second row
    }
    $i++; //increment
}
```

Comment: He is doing so in mutually exclusive if statements.

Comment: Not needed, but it is cleaner code in my opinion. It's also dangerous to increment in the if statement here... once you hit 11 it will just loop with no additional output until the end of the recordset.

Comment: @DenisErmolin - Sorry, I see what you meant now... else will suffice :)

Comment: You know, I have no idea what worked, but it just fixed itself somehow. thank you for helping me get to SLEEP TIME!

Answer (score 2):

You are incrementing `$i` inside both `if` statements. When `$i` is 10 it incremented to 11. But your second `if` is more than 11 which means that `$i` must be 12 and nowhere `$i` is incremented.

Two suggestions:

1. increment `$i` outside `if`'s
2. do `if {} else {}` statement

Answer (score 0):

A bit of refactoring can help you see your code a little clearer.

```
$i = 0;
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT type, info, url FROM alerts WHERE username = '$user_logged_in' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 40");
$div_grid = '<div style="float:left;">';

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    $displayStyle = 'float:left; margin-left:-22px;';

    if ($i > 11) $displayStyle .= ' margin-top:14px;';

    $display = '<a href="' . $row['info'] . '"><div class="' . $row['type'] . "_alert" . '" style="' . $displayStyle . '"></div></a>';
    $div_grid .='<div style="float:left;">' . $display . '</div>';
    $i++;

}

$div_grid .= '</div>';

echo $div_grid;
```

Most of the code inside your if/elseif blocks are duplicated. Extracting the similarities out and only having the difference inside the if statement ends up simplifying things quite a bit.